# Read every 5th line until the end of the text file

Tags: vb.net

Hi could someone please give me an example of how to read through a text file to the end and read every 5th line as a string? I know how to read a specific line in the text file using

line = System.IO.file.readAllLines(filepath)(linenum)

and also using streamreader to read each line etc..

But I want to go through the whole text file and pick out every certain number of lines. Pretty sure it's got something to do with a loop but I'm not too clued up yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As files are not line based, you would need to read all the lines and pick out the ones that you want.

You can use the `Where` method with the overload that gives you the index of the item, and the `Mod` operator to determine where every fifth line is:

```
Dim lines As String() = _
  System.IO.File.ReadLines(filepath).Where(Function(line, i) i Mod 5 = 0).ToArray()
```

The number that you compare the expression to determines which lines you get. `i Mod 5 = 0` starts at the first line and then every fifth from there, while `i Mod 5 = 4` starts at the fifth line and then every fifth from there.

(The `ReadLines` method is better than the `ReadAllLines` for this, as it doesn't read all the lines into memory first, but returns an enumerator so that you can process the lines as they are read.)

Comment: Since the array would be zero indexed, shouldn't it be something like `(i + 1) Mod 5 = 0`?

Comment: @roryap: That depends on the interpretation of "every 5th". I just added an explanation of how that works.

Comment: @Guffa Your addition regarding `ReadLines` vs `ReadAllLines` is true but totally defeated by the use of `ToArray` which will process the operation eagerly "on the spot"

Comment: @Sehnsucht: Not at all, having the `ToArray` at the end only realises the final result as an array, it doesn't cause all lines from the file to be read into memory before processing them.